# Manipulating the index of csv file with python

Tags: pandas, csv

I have a quite big csv file that I need to sort (making several smaller csv files).

My code for the file looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=";",decimal=",", index_col=0)
index = df.index
columns = df.columns
values = df.values
```

The files has three columns, let's call them A,B,C with A and C having numerical values and B text. The Index is 0-1000.

I would like to have A as an index and B,C as columns as they were. How can I do this?

In a second step, I would like to sort the file according to the text descriptions in B.

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: if A is indeed your first column, I would think that your argument *index_col=0* would already import column A as your index...

Answer (score 0):

For the first part use [df.set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)

```
df.set_index("A", inplace=True)
```

For the second part do you want to sort alphabetically or based on something else? Use [df.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) for this

```
df.sort_values(by="B", axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Step 1 worked perfectly. In Step 2 I would like to sort it by a specific reoccurring value. Say B consists of several reoccurring values: buy, sell, rent - I would like to have all the ones with the value buy.

Comment: [df.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) is probably the best was to do this.

df.groupby(by="B") will separate the frame by the values in column B. Then you can write each of the 'groups' out to a new csv file.